# Как указать в псевдоклассе ":not" несколько селекторов?

Tags: css, scss

Есть несколько классов вида `.card-outline-*`, где звездочка - цвет.

Также есть класс `.card`. Хочу для `.card` передать в псевдокласс `:not` все эти `.card-outline-*`, но не могу понять, как задействовать звездочку.

Или так нельзя и нужно перечислить все классы вручную?

Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: А вы пробовали? Что получилось?

Comment: @labris Пробовал писать так: `&:not(.card-outline-*)`. Редактор ругается.

Comment: Попробуйте попросту:  .card:not(.card-outline-*){атрибут:значение;}

Comment: проще всего добавить для этих элементов еще один общий класс, и делать выборку по нему

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это вам нужно про [комбинации селекторов](http://htmlbook.ru/css) почитать в нижней части списка. Откроете для себя множество полезных свойств в CSS.

Конкретно по примеру:

```css
.card {color: pink}
.card-outline-red {color: red;}
.card-outline-green {color: green;}
.card-outline-blue {color: blue;}
.card span:not([class^="card-outline-"]) {color: orange;}
```

```html
<div class="card">
<span class="card-outline-red">text</span>
<span class="card-outline-green">text</span>
<span class="card-outline-blue">text</span>
<span>span</span>
</div>
```

Вот так: `[class^="card-outline-"]` мы зацепляем все элементы которые начинаются с `card-outline-...`, в которых изменяется название цвета.

Comment: не угадал, `^=` - это, не _все элементы содержащие класс_, а _все элементы, в которых значение атрибута class **начинается с**_

Comment: Да, малость оговорился. Для всех классов подойдет `*=`